# how to Get previous three months date based on a from date and to date parameter value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have to  compare the sales on given based on the parameter from and to date at last three months.

```
Create table Net_sales 
(terminalid varchar(14),
Region varchar(20),
City varchar(50),
ICC_TRNS_COUNT int,
ICC_AMount money,
Trns_Date datetime)
```

```
--SELECT * FROM Net_sales

insert into Net_sales values ('INMAA031000000','SOUTH','CHENNAI',1,5000,'08/01/2019')
insert into Net_sales values ('INMAA031000000','SOUTH','CHENNAI',1,4000,'08/02/2019')
insert into Net_sales values ('INMAA031000000','SOUTH','CHENNAI',1,200,'08/04/2019')


insert into Net_sales values ('INAMD03900030G','WEST','Gujarat',1,52000,'08/01/2019')
insert into Net_sales values ('INAMD03900030G','WEST','Gujarat',1,40700,'08/02/2019')
insert into Net_sales values ('INAMD03900030G','WEST','Gujarat',1,2200,'08/04/2019')


insert into Net_sales values ('INAMD03900030G','WEST','Gujarat',1,52000,'09/01/2019')
insert into Net_sales values ('INAMD03900030G','WEST','Gujarat',1,47000,'09/02/2019')
insert into Net_sales values ('INAMD03900030G','WEST','Gujarat',1,2200,'09/10/2019')

insert into Net_sales values ('INAMD03900030G','WEST','Gujarat',1,52000,'10/01/2019')
insert into Net_sales values ('INAMD03900030G','WEST','Gujarat',1,70000,'10/02/2019')
insert into Net_sales values ('INAMD03900030G','WEST','Gujarat',1,3200,'10/10/2019')
```

```
-------------------
DECLARE @FROMDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @TODAY DATETIME 
SET @FROMDATE='08/01/2019'
SET @TODAY='10/10/2019'

SELECT 
TERMINALID ,
CITY,
REGION,
SUM(ICC_AMOUNT) ICASHDMRAMOUNT
FROM NET_SALES WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR,TRNS_DATE,101) BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,@FROMDATE,101) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,@TODAY,101)
GROUP BY TERMINALID ,
CITY,
REGION 
ORDER  BY TERMINALID
```

we need to expected and result
Expected result

```
TERMINALID  CITY    REGION  ICASHDMRAMOUNT_AUG  ICASHDMRAMOUNT_SEP  ICASHDMRAMOUNT_OCT
INAMD030001024  Gujarat WEST    94200   94200   94200
INAMD03900030G  Gujarat WEST    94900   101200  125200
INMAA031000000  CHENNAI SOUTH   5000    0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

`TerminalID` INAMD030001024 doesn't exist in your sample data, so it's not in the sample result set.

Your dates are stored as dates, so leave them that way. When you convert them to strings, date functions no longer work properly on them. Also, it's best to use [ANSI/ISO standard date format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#ansi-and-iso-8601-compliance), which is `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. Using `'MM/DD/YYYY'` could be misinterpreted as `'DD/MM/YYY'` depending on the regional settings on your servers. The standard form will always be interpreted correctly by the server.

With that said, your query just requires some conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  TERMINALID,
  CITY,
  REGION,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(TRNS_DATE) = 8 THEN ICC_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS ICASHDMRAMOUNT_AUG,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(TRNS_DATE) = 9 THEN ICC_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS ICASHDMRAMOUNT_SEP,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(TRNS_DATE) = 10 THEN ICC_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS ICASHDMRAMOUNT_OCT
FROM 
 NET_SALES WHERE TRNS_DATE BETWEEN @FROMDATE AND @TODAY
GROUP BY 
  TERMINALID ,
  CITY,
  REGION 
ORDER BY 
  TERMINALID;
```

Results:

```
TERMINALID  CITY    REGION  ICASHDMRAMOUNT_AUG  ICASHDMRAMOUNT_SEP  ICASHDMRAMOUNT_OCT
INAMD03900030G  Gujarat WEST    94900   101200  125200
INMAA031000000  CHENNAI SOUTH   9200    0   0
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/42bfbc/3/0

If you edit the Fiddle data to include the missing TerminalID, you should get to your precise desired results.

*EDIT:* If you need this to be a rolling three months, create a variable, maybe @FinalMonth int, set that to the value of `MONTH(@TODAY)`, then in the `CASE` expressions, use `@FinalMonth-2, @FinalMonth-1, @FinalMonth` rather than the hard coded values above. Your column names won't have month names in them without doing some dynamic SQL, but `_CurrMnth, _PrevMnth, _2ndPrevMnth` or something like that would get your point across.

Comment: ,Thanks for your reply almost result will came out and amount column should  be change dynamically based on the parameter ICASHDMRAMOUNT_AUG is there any option to do that

Comment: Yes, dynamic column names are possible, but as I noted in passing, that will require using dynamic SQL. Search for something like "SQL dynamic column names" to get yourself started. If you run into trouble with it, you should post a new question about it when you start to get close to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Will try it out for Dynamic col name .